# Selecting time-based data

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to achieve is grab data from the database, depending on the time.

For example, I may have multiple `prices` for an item, and I would like the new price to be effective based on the time and date. So I can schedule price changes in advance.

```
id   link_id   datetime               price
-------------------------------------------
2    11        2016-11-03 00:00:00    1020
3    11        2016-11-03 01:00:00    1050
4    11        2016-11-03 03:00:00    1090
```

Let's say the time is `2016-11-03 00:59:00`, when a user queries the db they will se the `price-1020`. But when they query the db a minute later at `2016-11-03 01:00:00` they should get `price-1050`.

Have tried this `WHERE datetime < UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, however this does not solve my problem. Also it only needs to select one entry, this selects multiple.

Is there a way MySQLi can do this?

Comment: Edit your question and show the entire query.

Comment: I've posted a new question where you can see the entire query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450332/mysqli-time-based-subqueries @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking for one item, I would expect something like this:

```
select p.*
from prices p
where p.item_id = $item_id and  -- however you are representing items
      p.datetime <= now()  -- or UTC Timestamp if that is how the date/time is represented
order by p.datetime desc
limit 1;
```

I could speculate that "`link_id`" refers to "items".

Comment: I can't have limit...I have left joins and this targets multiple result. What is a way to do it without a join? `link_id` does but this is a super simplified version of my query.

Comment: @Borsn . . . It is only possible to answer the question that is asked.  You should ask *another* question that is more similar to the query that you actually have.